# Is it possible to use html purifier without having it close open tags?

Tags: htmlpurifier

I am building a page dynamically and I need to run purifier on snippets just to avoid any scripting, however the div's are not yet closed and other content (that cannot be purified) is later inserted in it. So I would like to run purifier on the individual bits, however it automatically closes that tags, which is a no go zone in that case.

I can't find config options that allow me to disable closing open tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as you have noticed, it's not possible to disable. It's also a fairly important component, as it prevents user content from leaking into the rest of the page.

Comment: Thanks alot for answering. Do you have any idea what would be my best option for trying to prevent scripts from coming through?

Comment: Stop worrying about HTML Purifier closing your tags?

Comment: it kills the page, because the closing tags are supplied by the user after the dynamic elements they ask as children. Eg, the user makes a div, writes his css for it, puts a some h1 and p elements in it etc, leaves the div open. in the next config elem they ask a form to be constructed by the software, in the next elem they close their div, open a new one and go on. I wouldn't have written it like that, I would have done some template system, but if one secures software by others, one doesn't always have the choice.